# Ionic web output

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I would like to develop a website and mobile apps(android, ios) with same functionality. I want to reuse the web page code for mobile platforms.
Is ionic good for me?
Can I add different looking / functionality for my web page or it have to be same?

Comment: Short and simple: yes and yes.

Comment: If you have build a super responsive web app and want to use as it is in mobile apps so cordova is good for you not ionic because you do not need ionic customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the ionic mobile platform good for you because you
are website developer so you have knowledge about JavaScript, jQuery,
css, AngularJs, HTML right, and in using Ionic platform this is
technology we are used for developing mobile application only. You have
to get some knowledge about Cordova plugins because PhoneGap, Ionic is
totally plugins based architecture.